# Problem to Insert at n-th position in a singly circular linked list of integers

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Here's my code to insert a node at n-th position in a singly circular linked list. When tail is `NULL`, I'm trying to just return but that gives me a run time error. For this particular code, I am getting 8 printed while tail is `NULL` and not when `pos == 1` which should be the case. And for this wrong insertion pattern, I'm getting a list printed in reverse order when `display()` is called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node *tail; 
void insert(int data, int pos) {
    struct node *temp1 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data = data;
    struct node *temp2;
    if (tail == NULL) {
        temp1->link = temp1;
        tail = temp1;
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
        temp1->link = tail->link;
        tail->link = temp1;
    } else {
        temp2 = tail->link;
        for (int i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++) {
            temp2 = temp2->link;
        }
        temp1->link = temp2->link;
        temp2->link = temp1;
    }
} 

void display() {
    printf("List is \n");
    if (tail == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    struct node *temp;
    temp = tail->link;
    do {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    } while (temp != tail->link);
    printf("\n");
}

main() {
    tail = NULL;
    insert(8, 1);
    display();
    insert(3, 2);
    display();
    insert(7, 3);
    display();
    insert(9, 4);
    display(); 
}
```

It prints `9->7->3->8` and not `8->3->7->9`.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post your _entire_ code, properly indented. We need to see your `struct node` definition and your `display` function. Your code should compile _cleanly_, be downloadable and runnable by responders.

Comment: The way your code is structured, you still try to do a regular insertion after setting the `tail` when adding to an empty list. Either `return` after `tail=temp1` or use `else if (pos == 1) ...`

Comment: I have edited and gave the entire code.

Comment: Your `insert` function is simply wrong. You seem to want `tail` to point to the last element in the list, but when you insert a new element in the (new) last place, you don't reset `tail`.

Comment: tail==NULL is where I think I'm wrong. just adding a return statement inside the if body gives me no output. Assigning tail=temp1 gives me a garbage value for the first insert call. What should be the corner case ?

Comment: All right, **stop.** You are thrashing around, changing the code without understanding what it's doing, hoping to hit on something that gives the right answer. That approach can work, but it's monstrously slow. I advise you to implement a *non-circular* linked list, just a regular singly-linked list, and get it working perfectly, with an `insert` function and everything. Once you have that working perfectly, you'll find the circular version much easier.